# Bind int as enum in Razor Pages handler

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, enums, razor-pages

I'm using ASP.NET Core Razor Pages 7.

An enum:

```cs
public enum Animals { None = 0, Dog, Cat, Rat }
```

In some page's markup:

```html
<select id="Animal" name="Animal">
  <option value="" selected>Select an animal</option>
  <option value="1">Dog</option>
  <option value="2">Cat</option>
  <option value="3">Rat</option>
</select>
```

Notice that I've rendered them as ints rather than enum values.

In the page's code behind:

```cs
[BindProperty] public Animals Animal { get; set; }     // an enum
```

That enum is always bound to `None` rather than the value I choose from the select control.

A workaround is this:

```cs
[BindProperty] public int AnimalInt { get; set; }
public Animals Animal => (Animals)AnimalInt;
```

But that workaround is messy and less maintainable. Another approach is a custom model binder, but I hope that's unnecessary.

So, *assuming I'm rendering ints rather than enum values*, is there a built-in way to bind to enum values rather than ints?

---

NOTE: further to responses below, notice from above that I know how to render an enum to a select. The trouble is in the reverse: binding the selected int to an enum value in the razor page's POST handler.

Comment: try the Custom Model Binding
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @AntonyKao Yes I think that's probably the only option. I suspect the built-in model binder doesn't typecast int to enum.

Comment: It requires type casting sir, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, assuming I'm rendering ints rather than enum values, is there a
> built-in way to bind to enum values rather than ints?

Actually, within [IHtmlHelper interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.ihtmlhelper?view=aspnetcore-7.0) wee have [GetEnumSelectList()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.ihtmlhelper.getenumselectlist?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-rendering-ihtmlhelper-getenumselectlist(system-type)) which can get enum value using IHtmlHelper. As you can see below:

[image]

Amimal Enum:

```
public enum Animal
    {
        [Display(Name = "None")] None = 0,
        [Display(Name = "Dog")] Dog = 1,
        [Display(Name = "Cat")] Cat = 2,
        [Display(Name = "Rat")] Rat = 3,
    }
```

**Note:** Anything with 0 value would be selected by default as default of an enum is 0.

Render Razor View:

```
@using RazorPageDemoApp.Enum
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <table style="border-spacing: 12px;">
            <tr>            
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><strong>Setting Dropdown Default Value From Enum</strong></td>
                <td>@Html.DropDownList("Animal", Html.GetEnumSelectList<Animal>(),  new { @class = "form-control" })</td>

            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

**Note:**  Here I have an enum folder which I am refering here as ProjectName.Enum: That is:  [image]

Output:

[image]

**Update:**

Request Model:

```
public class RequestModel
    {

        public Animal Animal { get; set; }
    }
```

Request Method:

```
public void OnPost(RequestModel requestModel)
        {
            var getEnumValue = requestModel.Animal;
            var getEnumIndex = (int)requestModel.Animal;
        }
```

Submit View:

```
@using RazorPageDemoApp.Enum
<form class="form-group" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <table style="border-spacing: 12px;">
                <tr>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Setting Dropdown Default Value From Enum</strong></td>
                    <td>@Html.DropDownList("Animal", Html.GetEnumSelectList<Animal>(),  new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But this isn't what I'm after. I know how to render an enum to a select of ints (as I've noted above). What I failed to do was bind the selected value when posting the form. In the page's code behind class, I want it bound as an enum value, but it is bound as an int. A very nice answer otherwise, but for a different question :-) (Maybe find a suitable question and copy-paste this answer there, it's very comprehensive and useful.)

Comment: Thanks for your response, did you mean you want to get enum index from passed animal name? Because The way I showed already passing enum name. Anyway, I am updating the answer with either way.

Comment: Thanks, problem must be on my side then. I'd use the modern tag helper instead (see Mike's answer), but other than that this is great - it shows the process both in the forward (to markup) and reverse (to code) directions.

Comment: Thanks for your response and I personally prefer to take the advantange of TagHelper class which seems less clumsy.

Answer (score 1):

The default model binder happily binds to an `enum`. There is no need to cast anything. Here's the relevant working parts of my code:

```
public enum Animals
{
    None = 0, Dog, Cat, Sheep, Cow, Horse
}

[BindProperty] 
public Animals Animal { get; set; }

<form method="post">
    <select asp-for="Animal" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Animals>()"></select>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Problem must be on my side then, thanks for confirming!